# Closing resource created by timed-out future

Tags: scala, timeout, future

When we have method which creates a resource sometimes it is necessary to wait only specified duration. For example we want to wait 10 seconds to connect to a DB.

I tried to use future and Await.result to obtain that. Unfortunately, Await.result throws exception after specified time but do not kill future in progress. So after timeout we end up with TimeoutException but if future finally complete, we do not have any ability to close returned result.
Example:

```
import java.io.Closeable
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.concurrent.future

object Test {
    object ConnectionManager {
        class Connection extends Closeable {
        println("Connected")
        override def close = println("DB closed")
        }

        def connect = {
        println("Connecting to DB...")
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 7)
        new Connection
        }
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val f = future {
        ConnectionManager.connect
        }
        try {
        val result = Await.result(f, 5 seconds)
        result.close
        } catch {
        case e: TimeoutException => println("Connection timeout")
        }
        Thread.sleep(10 * 1000)
        println("Finished")
    }
}
```

Result is:

> Connecting to DB...
>
> Connection timeout
>
> Connected
>
> Finished

So connection is created but never closed

Comment: Why using a Future if you awaits the result with a timeout? Basically a real timeout will throw an exception and will never create a connection.

Comment: I need to provide time out by my self. Not by external library. DB connection is only an example. Other examples are getting network resources and creating InputStream. If connection takes too long we would like to timeout such operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `f.onSuccess { case c => c.close }` to your `catch` clause.

Comment: Your solution is correct in spirit but won't compile.  The `onSuccess` method here takes a `PartialFunction[Connection,Unit]` and not a `Function1[Connection,Unit]`.  I believe it will work as `f.onSuccess{case c => c.close}`.

Comment: I will not interrupt future but for me it is close enough.